# MySQL JSON strings with PHP. fixing commas

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm creating this JSON thingy and I need to remove the last comma from it. (yes I know I could do a simple way instead of making the json myself, but I need it to be like this {"1":0,"2":4,"3":1.5}) So how can I do it? (And yes I have a working way in the code but it doesent display it like I need it.)

```
<?php
require 'dbConnect.script.php';

$query="SELECT * FROM `trash`";
if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query)){
    print "{";
    while($query_execute=$query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run)){

       echo '<tr><td>"'.$query_execute['id'].'"</td>:<td>'.$query_execute['weight'].',</td></tr>';
       //$rows = array();
       //$rows[] = $query_execute;

       //print json_encode($rows);

   }
   print "}";

}

else{

   echo "query notexecuted";

}
?>
```

Comment: It's useless. Use `json_encode`. Period.

Comment: json_encode makes a format that I couldent use therfor I need this :P

Comment: What you need is to fix the code which can't use standard `json_encode` output.

Comment: It's not me that created it so I cannot

Comment: json_encode displays [{"id":"1","weight":"0"}][{"id":"2","weight":"7"}][{"id":"3","weight":"1.5"}] but I need commas between not ][

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What are you going to use the json for? Your code doesn't relate to your json issue at all.

Comment: The first thing you should do is not using the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. Read on php.net how to use them and your problem might solve itself...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when I used mysqli it just shows errors. And the code is going to get used for a IoT prodject

Comment: @MagnusEriksson also the part which is marked out returns this [{"id":"1","weight":"0"}][{"id":"2","weight":"7"}][{"id":"3"‌​,"weight":"1.5"}] and not [{"id":"1","weight":"0"},{"id":"2","weight":"7"},{"id":"3"‌​,"weight":"1.5"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query)){ //Here you execute the query
   while($query_execute=$query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run)){  //Here you get one row from execution result

      $rows = array(); //You create array into $rows, what was in $rows before will be wiped
      $rows[] = $query_execute; // You insert one row you just fetch from result to $rows

      print json_encode($rows); // You encode $rows (which always has only one element as you wipe it every iteration)

  }
}
```

So, create array before loop, and encode that array after loop, adding elements to array inside a loop is ok.
-Mr_KoKa @LinusTechTips.com

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can simply create an array:

```
$array = ["1" => 0, "2" => 4, "3" => 1.5];
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Since this array doesn't start with a zero (which indexed arrays does), this would give you your desired result.

**If you want to start with a zero**, and still get an object back:

```
$array = ["0" => 2, "1" => 0, "2" => 4, "3" => 1.5];
```

you can use the option `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as a second parameter, like this:

```
$array = ["0" => 2, "1" => 0, "2" => 4, "3" => 1.5];
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This will give you:

```
{
    "0": 2,
    "1": 0,
    "2": 4,
    "3": 1.5
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

*It's seldom a good idea to build your own encoders/decoders for things like this. It usually gets quite complicated pretty quick, and you will spend most of your time straighten out bugs and get stuck on edge cases. It's better to read up on the native functions. They have been tried and tested for years, and are often much better in regards of performance.*

Comment: How should I get the values into the array?

Comment: You don't know how to create an array? You should start by reading some basic php tutorials...

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I concur `json_encode` is the nicest solution for producing JSON.  To produce a nice comma separated output you could use the `implode` function.

Set-up your elements in an array, so for example:

```
$data = array('"1":0', '"2":4', '"3":1.5');
```

Then use `implode` like this

```
$output = implode(',', $data);
```

Which will give you an output of the data elements in the array as a comma separated list

Comment: How should I get the values into the data?

Comment: Depends how they are being stored, are they computed or read from a database?  If you build a string with the desired element in you can add that to the end of the array with `$data[] = $yourString`